# How can I reverse 3D look_at function?

Tags: opengl, matrix, rust, 3d, camera

I am trying to transition from pre-defined cameras to free-look mode. I have `4x4` view matrices read from [glTF](https://www.khronos.org/gltf/) data. I think these are the same thing with what a [`look_at`](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.17.0/cgmath/struct.Matrix4.html#method.look_at_dir) function would return.

What I need to accomplish the transition is to extract `eye` and `look_at_dir` values from the 4x4 view matrix:

```rust
// Return (eye, look_at_dir)
decode(view_matrix: Matrix4<f32>) -> (Point3<f32>, Vector3<f32>)
```

---

I am using Rust, [gltf](https://crates.io/crates/gltf) crate, [cgmath](https://crates.io/crates/cgmath) crate and compile to wasm target. But I imagine the answer should be language independent.

Comment: By default the camera looks at -z direction from point [0, 0, 0]. Inside your `Matrix4` there are two main components: a 3x3 matrix of rotation and to the right of it there is a 3x1 column for transpose. So you may apply this 3x3 matrix to -z direction to get direction of the camera, and you can extract the 3x1 column to get it's position

Comment: @AlexLarionov I just tried this and it works! I will have to raycast and find a `focal_point` on some object, but it can be done later. For now I can say `focal_point` is `1` unit away from `eye` in `look_at_dir`. If you can turn this into an answer I would like to accept.

Comment: tbh I wasn't sure if it's 100% correct and by looking at Makogan's answer I think you can get away without applying the matrix, you can just straight take either 3rd row or 3rd column as `look_at_dir` (not sure which exactly), because it encodes where z direction goes after rotation, so to get where -z direction goes, you negate this row(column) and here's your `look_at_dir`. And again as Makogan suggests, getting `eye` might be trickier than I thought and I don't really know if it's as simple as taking the last column

Answer (score 1):

The `look_at_dir` is easy, assuming it follows the same matrix layout as glm, the third row is your look direction.

The eye is a bit more difficult.

The first three values of the last column are the eye if the look and up direction were colinear with the world axis.

If they were not colinear, that column has the coordinates of the eye position expressed in the orthonormal basis defined by the look direction, the vector of the cross product of the look direction with the up vector, and the cross product of those 2 vectors.

The up vector of that basis is the second row, and the side vector is the first, so to get the eye you need to express this basis in terms of your basis and then convert the coordinates of the eye position.

Answer (score 1):

The view space is the local system which is defined by the point of view onto the scene.
The position of the view, the line of sight and the upwards direction of the view, define a coordinate system relative to the world coordinate system. The objects of a scene have to be drawn in relation to the view coordinate system, to be "seen" from the viewing position. The inverse matrix of the view coordinate system is named the **view matrix**. This matrix transforms from world coordinates to view coordinates.

[`look_at_dir`](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.18.0/cgmath/struct.Matrix4.html#method.look_at_dir) defines the view matrix with the `eye` position, the viewing direction (`dir`) and th `up` vector. `eye`, `dir` and `up` are positions respectively vectors in world space, which define the the position and orientation of the camera in world space. `eye`, `dir` and `up` define the view space. If you would setup a matrix by this vectors, then the matrix would transform from view space to world space.
Since the view matrix has to do the opposite (world space -> view space), the view matrix is the [inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) of that matrix which is defined by `eye`, `dir` and `up`. [`look_at_dir`](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.18.0/cgmath/struct.Matrix4.html#method.look_at_dir) computes the inverse matrix of that matrix which is defined by `eye`, `dir` and `up`.

If you want to get the `eye` position from the view matrix, you need to compute the [inverse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix). The `eye` position is the translation (4th column) of the resulting matrix. Use [`invert`](https://docs.rs/cgmath/0.18.0/cgmath/prelude/trait.SquareMatrix.html#tymethod.invert) to compute the inverse matrix of the view matrix.

Minimal example:

```rust
use cgmath::prelude::*;
use cgmath::{Matrix4, Point3, Vector3};

fn main() {
    let view_mat = Matrix4::look_at_dir(
        Point3::new(0.0, 5.0, 0.0),    // eye
        Vector3::new(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0), // dir
        Vector3::new(0.0, 0.0, 1.0),   // up
    );

    let view_mat_inv = view_mat.invert().unwrap();

    println!("view matrix translation: ({}, {}, {})", view_mat[3][0], view_mat[3][1], view_mat[3][2]);
    println!("eye: ({}, {}, {})", view_mat_inv[3][0], view_mat_inv[3][1], view_mat_inv[3][2]);
}
```

Output:

> ```non
> view matrix translation: (-3.5355339059327378, 0, -3.5355339059327373)
> eye: (0, 5, 0)
> ```